# GridView child bring to front in android 4.4

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, bringtofront

There is apparently a bug in Android which breaks View.bringToFront.
In a GridView , I want to bring a child View to front by calling bringToFront(),When I call this method on child view , the child is moved to the bottom right position in the GridView.
I don't know how to solve this. Any help should be appreciated.